# Issue with Kendo ToDataSource(request) build error

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Simple stuff, trying to get an idea on how this works.  I am missing something obvious.
I have the kendo.mvc referenced correct vers.
I am getting

> System.Collections.Generic.List<SessiondataDTO>' does not contain a definition for 'addTestSessiondata' and no extension method 'addTestSessiondata' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SessiondataDTO>' could be found

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
```

Model class

```
public class SessiondataDTO
{
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public string serverName { get; set; }
    public string applicationName { get; set; }
    public string farmName { get; set; }
    public string domainName { get; set; }
    public int sessionID { get; set; }
    public string resultmsg { get; set; }
    public bool isInError { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }

    public List<SessiondataDTO> addTestSessiondata()
    { 
        List<SessiondataDTO> sessiondatas = new List<SessiondataDTO>();

        sessiondatas.Add(new SessiondataDTO { userID = "jayc", applicationName = "testapp1", domainName = "MS", farmName = "testfarm1", serverName = "wtxw0000", sessionID = 12 });
        sessiondatas.Add(new SessiondataDTO { userID = "jayc", applicationName = "testapp44", domainName = "MS", farmName = "testfarm1", serverName = "wtx44444", sessionID = 19 });
        sessiondatas.Add(new SessiondataDTO { userID = "jayc", applicationName = "testapp99", domainName = "MS", farmName = "testfarm1", serverName = "wtxw00890", sessionID = 10 });
        sessiondatas.Add(new SessiondataDTO { userID = "jayc", applicationName = "testapp1", domainName = "MS", farmName = "testfarm1", serverName = "wtxep0000", sessionID = 45 });           
        return sessiondatas;
    }
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult JLO()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult sessions_read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        List<SessiondataDTO> sdto = new List<SessiondataDTO>();

        sdto.addTestSessiondata();

        DataSourceResult result = sdto.ToDataSourceResult(request,);

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Everything builds fine but I keep getting that error.  I am using a simple `List<>` and trying to use the extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addTestSessiondata is not an extension method, but you are attempting to use it as such. Try:

```
public ActionResult sessions_read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<SessiondataDTO> sdto = addTestSessiondata();

    DataSourceResult result = sdto.ToDataSourceResult(request);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Sometimes I miss the obvious.